# Should I call out recruiters if I suspect there is no real offer?

Tags: recruitment

Should you call out a recruiter from any of the popular social media pages?
I got a message an just responded out of curiosity and I am pretty sure there is no real specific offer as he stated in his first message, so he just wants to generate a lead to user later and scoop my CV in the meantime.

He could not list any specific details about the position, when I asked about the compensation and if it fits my bounds he said that's discussable depending on the experience I have, which is clearly visible in my profile which I keep quite updated.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "call out?" And, what would you hope to achieve by doing so?

Answer (score 13):

> I got a message an just responded out of curiosity and i am pretty sure there is no real specific offer as he stated in his first message

If you don't like what they offer or of this seems suspicious to you then politely decline their offer and move on.

No need to call out or post on social media, as currently this is just a suspicion you have, and there is little you can gain by doing it.

Comment: I did not mean to call them out on social media, rather tell them in the private messages

Comment: @joachim again, what would you gain by doing that. If it's suspicious to you just move on, and use your valuable time to search for other opportunities instead. You are already chatting with them via messages. Replying to them that you think their offer is fake will hardly make it real in case this were just a bait.